# How to list 404 ressources error via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, logging, http-status-code-404, firebug

I might have some interesting clue here...

Facts are I'm currently on some website, which I don't have access to the "medias" server . thus don't have any clue on its logs and can't get the logged 404 errors.

When testing I do sometimes have a 404 error related to some CSS contents or whatever. Firebug does its nice job displaying them, but I want to log them on the client side now.

I tried a huge workaround in JavaScript to return the appropriate header via AJAX, so far this excludes all background properties of CSS style sheets.

Those questions remain:

- Is there a way to catch the Firebug network output?
- Or is there a simple way of doing this via JavaScript or another creative clever solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you make an `XMLHttpRequest` to a resource, it should give you a response header. `200` for example when found, but `404` when not.

You do need all resources to be known and tested.

Consider this code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.onreadystatechange = readyStateXML;
request.open("get", url, true);
request.send(null);

function readyStateXML()
{
    if (this.readyState == 4)
    {
        //404 or 400, not found error
        if (this.status == "400" || this.status == "404")
        {
            console.log("404: The requested page isn't found.");
        }
        else if(this.status == "500")
        {
            console.log("500: Internal server error.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebug [uses internal Firefox APIs](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/bf882ad8c0c33253b6ff8f1f9af39434a1a22473/extension/content/firebug/net/requestObserver.js#L20) to get the [HTTP request information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests) including the HTTP status code of the response.
This information is just available to code with specific privileges and is **not** exposed to the page itself. So if you want to access the status code of all requests your page makes, you need to write an extension for your browser.

For AJAX requests you do within your JavaScript, you can get their HTTP status via the [`status` property of the `XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#status).

```
function makeRequest(url) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onreadystatechange = function logStateChange() {
    if (req.readyState === 4) {
      // 'req.status' contains the HTTP status code of the response
      console.log(req.status);
    }
  }

  req.open('GET', url);
  req.send();
}
```